# MySQL conditional insert causing Error Code 1364: "Field doesn't have a default value"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, mysql-error-1364

I have added a new column to my table `quote_entry` (which already has several columns) with this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE quote_entry
ADD overtime_id INTEGER;
```

Now, I'm trying to insert data into the column like this:

```
INSERT INTO quote_entry (overtime_id)
select 1
FROM quote_entry 
WHERE overtime=0;
```

But this is giving me an error message:

```
Error: Field 'quote_id' doesn't have a default value
SQLState:  HY000
ErrorCode: 1364
```

I don't understand, why am I getting this error when I'm just trying to modify data in the `overtime_id` column?

Comment: you've got a `quote_id` field in your `quote_entry` table which DOESN'T have a default value, and since you're not providing a value for that field in your `insert...select` query, mysql is properly rejecting your query.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured out. But I don't want to add new lines, just modify the ones already in the table. (i'm sorry if it's not clear, my English is not so rich)

thanks for your quickly answer !

Comment: then you need to have an `on duplicate key update ...` structure, or use an `update` query, not a plain insert. `insert` = create new record.

Comment: Ah ok... I'm gonna look for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `INSERT` statement is used to add new rows to a table. It looks like what you want to do is add values to the column you just created, in the existing rows. You would do this with [an `UPDATE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) instead of an `INSERT` statement:

> ```
> UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
>     SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
>     [WHERE where_condition]
>     [ORDER BY ...]
>     [LIMIT row_count]
> ```

The simple version, without unnecessary options, would look like this:

```
UPDATE table_reference SET col_name=expr WHERE where_condition;
```

In this case, `expr` will be a constant expression – `1` – if you want to leave the column `NULL` in all rows where your condition doesn't match.